# How to get client file path when upload file asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to take client file path, maybe by javascript or server side code (use asp.net MVC). Anyone meet this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible and should not be possible.
This was possible in IE6 but for obvious reasons this is a major security issue.

If you want to obtain a path name from the local file system you will have to ask the user to manually enter it or use a java or flash plugin.

Answer (score 0):

it may be possible by doing this...

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFile File) {

    var clientPath = Path.GetFullPath(File.FileName);
    return view();

}
```